# Minify all images assets using webpack (regardless whether they were imported)

Tags: javascript, webpack, minify

I am going through webpack tutorials and it teaches how it is possible to minify and output images that have been imported in main index.js file.

However I would like to minify all image assets, regardless whether they were imported in the index.js or not. Something that was easily done in gulp by having a watch set up on the folder. Does webpack follow same format?

This is my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  module: {
    rules : [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[ext]'
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
          }
         ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, webpack does not follow the same "logic" as gulp. Webpack """""watches""""" for changes in files that are linked throughout the entire dependency tree. This means that the file you wan't to touch **HAS TO BE** imported somewhere.

Comment: That is a bit lame... suppose I have a simple `<img>` in my html only. And I want it to `src` to dist folder, expecting a file to be there... but since none of my `.js` files imports it, I won't have it in dist folder?

Comment: No, you won't. You could use a "copy-webpack-plugin" to copy every single *.jpg there and then you could reference them as ./img.jpg. Its a workaround

Comment: copy without minifiying?